# Crm 2015 Javascript Context is not defined from fetchxml

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I want to get values from `fetchxml` using javascript in html web resource.I use crm 2015. The code block is in the attachment on [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLH2.jpg).

After the fetchxml, I try to get values with soap function.
it gives me the error

> Error: Contex is not available

I added the `xrmservicetoolkit` for crm 2015 and jquery and json files. What is the problem? How can I solve this? Can anyone help me please?

```
var fetch = "<fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical'><entity name='quote'>";
  fetch += "<all-attributes />";
  fetch += "<filter type='and'>";
  fetch += "<condition attribute='new_anabayi' operator='eq' value='" + id + "' />";
  fetch += "<condition attribute='statuscode' operator='eq' value='1' />";
  fetch += "<condition attribute='customertypecode' operator='eq' value='7' />";
  fetch += "</filter></entity></fetch>";

var fetchData = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(fetch);
```

Comment: please include your code as *text*, not as screenshot

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to [ClientGlobalContext.js](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328541.aspx) on your web resource.

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am assuming you already have referenced the following scripts too?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="XrmServiceToolkit.js"></script>
```

Comment: ClientGlobalContext.js isn't for CRM 2015 - at least, it says so on the link you included.